# HTML to make a PDF display at a certain size when clicked

Tags: html, pdf, browser-plugin

I have an uploaded PDF which, when clicked in the browser, is displayed using Adobe or whatever plugin the user has.  But it's a pretty large file, so I'm wondering if there is a way to have it open, say, a specific size or percentage of original.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to open it at a specific percentage or in fit view mode. You set the document's Open action with a Goto action that targets the page you want to display. When you set the target page you also have the option to set the desired zoom or a Fit mode.